# Regular Expression contains characters with model state validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

```
[RegularExpression(@"/^(?=.*[_$@.])(?=.*[^_$@.])[\w$@.]$/", ErrorMessage = "UserName should contain At least one letter")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Valid:-

```
abc@123#
abc
@sad
```

And Not Valid

```
.
@.@
///
@@@
```

I have tried a lot of regex code, but couldn't achieve the expected output.
Here are the valid and invalid formats which needs to be accepted and rejected respectively.

and sorry for my english.

Comment: do you want to check the username has atleast one character?

Comment: yes at least one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as long as the `UserName` contains at least 1 alphabet character it's valid? Try this:

```
^.*[a-zA-Z].*$
```